# Caching problem in custom blade directive - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I've created a custom blade directive `@admin ... @endadmin` in `AppServiceProvider`. But this directive is getting cached. That's why I've to run `php artisan view:clear` command each time after new login. What is the best way to use custom blade directive without hampering the performance?

Here is the logic in `boot` method of `AppServiceProvider`

```
Blade::directive('admin', function () {
    $isAuth = 'false';
    if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->role_id == 3) {   
        $isAuth = 'true';
    }
    return "<?php if ($isAuth): ?>";
});
Blade::directive('endadmin', function () {
    return "<?php endif; ?>";
});
```

Comment: Need to see logic for directive

Comment: I've added the logic but I think caching is the main issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blade views, and therefor blade directives, are rendered to php files only once after they have been updated. In you case, the auth state will be checked for the very first visit of the page.

To make the directive check the auth state on every request, you have to send the php code back to the view as a string so it can be executed every time.

You can find out what a rendered view looks like by checking the `storage/framework/views` folder. This contains all compiled views.

For your case, you would have to return something like this from your directive:

```
return '<?php if (auth()->user() && auth()->user()->role_id == 3): ?>';
```